# How to build links with fragments taken from text fields, but within a JavaScript to randomize them before open each of them on its own tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make one single JavaScript able to randomize several links **which must be built with fragments taken from text fields**, before opening each of them on its own tab, by clicking a button.

I know 2 different JavaScripts to separately do both things:

- a) build URLs with fragments taken from text fields
- b) randomize
  several links before opening each of them on its own tab

But I can't find a working way to blend the 2 of them together in one single JavaScript.

I have tried several options to accomplish this, but I'm not an expert at all, so I keep failing and failing.

Wishing to make this post easier to be understood, I did a fiddle for it, but unfortunately links from fiddle are usually blocked on many websites, therefore I used w3schools pages instead, to make my example able to work properly:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GT70R73WAL8A

My code so far is this:

```
var srchTwtrClbrts = [
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:ddlovato since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:jtimberlake since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:selenagomez since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:ArianaGrande since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:taylorswift13 since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:rihanna since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:katyperry since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:justinbieber since:"+a+" until:"+b+" "+c+" " },
 ];

var a=$("#searchSince").val(),b=$("#searchUntil").val(),c=$("#searchLiveOrTop").val();

$('#searchTwitterAccounts').click(function(searchTwitterAccounts) {
  for (var i = 0; i < srchTwtrClbrts.length; i++) {
      var order = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1 
      srchTwtrClbrts[i].order = order;
  }

  srchTwtrClbrts.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a.order - b.order);
  })

  for (var i = 0; i < srchTwtrClbrts.length; i++) {
      window.open(srchTwtrClbrts[i].url);
  }

})
```

At the w3schools page, you will need to click on **Run »** to watch the following:

[image: click "Run »"]

and then choose the content for each of the 3  fields.

If it helps in anyway, I suspect my problem is not having this line correctly located:

```
var a=$("#searchSince").val(),b=$("#searchUntil").val(),c=$("#searchLiveOrTop").val();
```

as the resulting URLs keep saying "**undefined**"

I'm open to all suggestions, even to modify this script completely, so please feel free to suggest anything.
All suggestions are welcome as all of them help a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when form data has been changed you never update the `srchTwtrClbrts`, So you need to listen to any change of text box and update the `srchTwtrClbrts`.

I add `formChange` class to main `div` and then listen to change of that:

```
<div class="formChange" name="searchCelebrities" id="searchCelebrities" style="display: flex; width: 400px; margin: 15px; height: 28px; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px gray dotted; background-color: #e2e2e2; padding: 5px 0 0 5px;">
        <span style="position: relative; top: 1px; margin-right: 5px;">from:</span>
        <form id="form-searchSince" style="margin-right: 5px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchSince" class="SrchTwtr" style="width: 100px !important; margin-right: 5px;">
        </form>
        <span style="position: relative; top: 1px; margin-right: 5px;">until:</span>
        <div id="form-searchUntil" style="margin-right: 5px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchUntil" class="SrchTwtr" style="width: 100px !important; margin-right: 5px;">
        </div>
        <form id="form-searchLiveOrTop">
            <label for="searchLiveOrTop"></label>
            <select id="searchLiveOrTop" name="searchLiveOrTop" class="SrchTwtr" style="width: 65px !Important; font-size: 0.85em !Important; padding-left: 0px !Important;">
                <option value=" ">Top</option>
                <option value="&f=live">Latest</option>
                <option value="&f=user">People</option>
                <option value="&f=image">Photos</option>
                <option value="&f=video">Videos</option>
            </select>
        </form>
</div>
```

And in script I create a function to update the `srchTwtrClbrts` when any changes happen:

```
var a = $("#searchSince").val(), b = $("#searchUntil").val(), c = $("#searchLiveOrTop").val();

var srchTwtrClbrts = [
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:ddlovato since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:jtimberlake since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:selenagomez since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:ArianaGrande since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:taylorswift13 since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:rihanna since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:katyperry since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:justinbieber since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
];

$(".formChange").change(function () {
    var a = $("#searchSince").val(), b = $("#searchUntil").val(), c = $("#searchLiveOrTop").val();
    upadteUrL(a, b, c);
});

function upadteUrL(a, b, c) {
    srchTwtrClbrts = [
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:ddlovato since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:jtimberlake since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:selenagomez since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:ArianaGrande since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:taylorswift13 since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:rihanna since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:katyperry since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
        { url: "https://twitter.com/search?q= from:justinbieber since:" + a + " until:" + b + " " + c + " " },
    ];
}

$('#searchTwitterAccounts').click(function (searchTwitterAccounts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < srchTwtrClbrts.length; i++) {
        var order = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
        srchTwtrClbrts[i].order = order;
    }

    srchTwtrClbrts.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a.order - b.order);
    })

    for (var i = 0; i < srchTwtrClbrts.length; i++) {
        window.open(srchTwtrClbrts[i].url);
    }
})
```

Comment: Alireza Ahmadi you are great! Not only solving our needs, but also sharing your knowledge, and teaching us to understand better. I really appreciate your help a lot. THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your patience, wisdom, teaching, and time spent on helping me and every other user here. All my gratitude. Rex.